# Unable to create a function-like template in C++

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates

I am trying to create a template class that takes as template parameters the return type and parameters of a function, for example: `new static_detour<int(const char*, int)>()`

As this is the same syntax we can see in the std function template, I tried to copy the same structure found in `function.h`, so this is my class so far:

```
template<typename Result, typename ... Arguments>
class static_detour<Result(Arguments...)>
{
}
```

However, this does not work, and when I try to use that file from a .cpp file the compiler throws `error C2988: unrecognizable template declaration/definition`. I fi remove the <> after the class name it compiles fine, but then I cannot use the `Arguments` parameter.

Is this possible in C++, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: what do you mean with " then I cannot use the Arguments parameter." ? of course you can use them

Comment: If I add a function such as `Result myFunction();` and then call it, the compiler says `error C2091: function returns function`, as it is trying to return the whole `int(const char*, int)>` as Result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to declare the *primary*, unconstrained class template, that defines the number of template arguments the class requires:

```
template <class T>
class static_detour;
```

*before* you can declare any complete or partial *specializations* of the class template, which accept only particular arguments:

```
template<typename Result, typename ... Arguments>
class static_detour<Result(Arguments...)>
{
}
```

The type `static_detour<T>` will refer to the specialization if `T` is of the form `Result(Arguments...)` for some `Result` and `Arguments...`, that is, if deduction against the specialization succeeds. Otherwise, it will refer to the primary template.

Comment: Thanks, that works! Although I've had to remove the <T>  from static_detour<T>.

Comment: Yup, that must've been a typo. @Brian, you don't want the `<T>` in your first declaration.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, my bad.